# Jest spyOn mockResolved with asynchronous tests seems to not work properly in certain condition, what's happening?

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, testing, jestjs

Recently I had to write some tests that mock API requests with jest (24.8.0).
So, I wrote something like this:

```js
class MyApi {
    public async getSomeData() {
        // request backend
    }
}

describe("Some test", () => {
    const apiSpy = jest.spyOn(MyApi, 'getSomeData');

    afterEach(() => jest.restoreAllMocks());

    test('some test 1', async () => {
        // arrange
        apiSpy.mockResolved(null);
        
        // act
        const result = await someFunctionCallingMyApi();

        // assert
    });

    test('some test 2', async () => {
        // arrange
        apiSpy.mockResolved(someMockObject);
        
        // act
        const result = await someFunctionCallingMyApi();

        // assert
    });
    // ...and more
});
```

but it appears that some `mockResolved` are ignored and my function is calling real API instead of mocked one.

Later I changed this code to:

```js
describe("Some test", () => {
    let apiSpy: jest.SpyInstance;

    beforeEach(() => {
        apiSpy = jest.spyOn(MyApi, 'getSomeData');
    });

    afterEach(() => jest.restoreAllMocks());

    test('some test 1', async () => {
        // arrange
        apiSpy.mockResolved(null);
        
        // act
        const result = await someFunctionCallingMyApi();

        // assert
    });

    test('some test 2', async () => {
        // arrange
        apiSpy.mockResolved(someMockObject);
        
        // act
        const result = await someFunctionCallingMyApi();

        // assert
    });
    // ...and more
});
```

and my tests seem to work, its properly call mocked function.

Can someone explain why the first code does not work?